# Is it possible to export the error list from Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I would like to know if it is somehow possible to export the Visual Studio 2008 error list, preferably in Excel format.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to change topic, `VS 2008` is too vague

Comment: @Snowbear: Submitted an edit for approval.

Comment: @Snowbear, to be fair, we are on stackoverflow, "VS 2008" is fairly unambiguous in that context =)

Comment: @Rob, sorry, wrong word. Not `vague`, but `not too narrow`. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: @Snowbear, never apologise for the fact that you're more fluent in english than many people who're native speakers! =) (I am assuming that you're russian and not a yank/brit/aussie/etc living there). But yes, I get what you mean, the answer *should* be applicable to any version of Visual Studio, hopefully =)

Answer (score 18):

1. In errors window `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+C`
2. Paste in Excel

Answer (score 4):

That's very... interesting, to say the least.

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in "Error List" window to select all items, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy them to the Clipboard and then paste in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Not automated, but:

1. Click anywhere in the error list
2. Type: CTRL-A, CTRL-C
3. Open Excel
4. Type: CTRL-V

You could probably automate this quite easily with a Visual Studio macro, which could be as simple as this:

```
DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE80.WindowKinds.vsWindowKindErrorList).Activate
DTE.ExecuteCommand ("Edit.SelectAll")
DTE.ExecuteCommand ("Edit.Copy")
```

That's been generated by recording a macro (Tools > Macros > Record). The exercise of moving it *out* of the clipboard and into a copy of Excel is one that I'll leave for you, as I've used Excel automation before and never want to again ;=)

Comment: i need some automation.but how do i using that VS macro? where can i serch for it

Comment: @Aravinth, I've added a basic sample that shows how to automate the process of getting the errors from the Error window into the clipboard. You could create that as a Visual Studio macro and attach it to a keyboard shortcut =)

Comment: @Rob, thanks for giving the tips for saving errors to clipborad.but i need paste the errors into excel file with specified location.I tried below code,but it is not working fine.Please let me know if any thing wrong ' System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("C:\\Aravinth\\Book1.xls") DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.PasteSpecial") how do i paste errors using macro command

Comment: @Aravinth, DTE.ExecuteCommand will only trigger things *in* Visual Studio, *not* in a process you've started from it. I'd suggest you ask a *new* question about automating Excel, as it's quite distinct from the "obtaining the error list" and you'll stand a better chance of getting a good answer =)

Comment: @Rob,is there any alternate way for automating excel

Comment: @Aravinth, I don't know. Ask another stackoverflow question "I have text in the clipboard, how do I use a Visual Studio Macro to automate Excel and get that text into a spreadsheet" - Your original question is really *two* questions =) (Although you do only say *preferably* in Excel)

Answer (score 2):

Error List Manager – Visual Studio Plugin

Error List Manager extension lets you perform extra actions on Visual Studio’s Error List Window like Export, Email, Print.

http://shemeerns.com/error-list-manager-plugin/